# Docker: each user only allowed to manage their own image and containers

Tags: docker, user-permissions

I have a server that is being shared with some fellow developers. All of us have the access to docker because when i added them, i add them to the docker group using `sudo usermod -aG docker username`.

So this server there are several people inside and recently my colleague accidentally deleted my container for some reason. How can i prevent this? I'm thinking about having user only can do something to their own container and image, but is this possible to be achieved in docker? or is there any solution?

Comment: as far as I know docker containers can run only as a root

Comment: you can try setting umask on linux os (https://www.linuxnix.com/umask-define-linuxunix/)

Comment: @AnarBayramov or with the user added to the docker group. you can run docker commands without need of sudo if the user is already in docker group